# What to do to UV coordinates, when swapping Z/Y coordinates (axis) of the geometry?

Tags: coordinates, 3dsmax, uv-mapping

In my Maxscript exporter I have the ability to flip the Z/Y axis by simply swapping the Z and Y co-ordinates.

When swapping the axis this way, what is the correct thing to do to the UV coordinates? (e.g. do I need to swap the U or V, or invert one or both?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're trying to change how the object is textured you shouldn't need to adjust the UVs at all.

Comment: You are correct - my apologies my entire object had been 'mirrored' which I took to be a mirrored texture. Next time I won't use symmetrical objects for testing...
Thank you!